# Why is my script not including the lat/long when I try geocoding address with ArcGIS?

Tags: python, arcgis, geocode

I'm trying to test the geocode method of the ArcGIS library but it's just returning the address I input. The code is as follows:

```
from geopy.geocoders import ArcGIS
arcgis = ArcGIS()
print(arcgis.geocode("2810 Fannin Ave, Midland, TX 79705"))
```

There aren't any errors thrown and it runs fine, but the output is:
2810 Fannin Ave, Midland, TX 79705

I thought it was supposed to take the given address and query a server containing more information and include that in the response. I'm guessing I am not using the library properly.

Answer (score 0):

The string representation of a geopy.location.Location is that class's address property. You can access other properties such as *address*, *latitude* by name. You can get a dictionary of all properties from *raw*

Example:

```
from geopy.geocoders import ArcGIS
result = ArcGIS().geocode("2810 Fannin Ave, Midland, TX 79705")
print(result.address)
print(result.altitude)
print(result.latitude)
print(result.longitude)
print(result.raw)
print(repr(result))
```

**Output:**

```
2810 Fannin Ave, Midland, Texas, 79705
0.0
32.01647500135772
-102.11659898148692
{'address': '2810 Fannin Ave, Midland, Texas, 79705', 'location': {'x': -102.11659898148692, 'y': 32.01647500135772}, 'score': 100, 'attributes': {}, 'extent': {'xmin': -102.11759898148692, 'ymin': 32.01547500135772, 'xmax': -102.11559898148691, 'ymax': 32.01747500135772}}
Location(2810 Fannin Ave, Midland, Texas, 79705, (32.01647500135772, -102.11659898148692, 0.0))
```

Comment: That makes sense thanks! I'm sure that will work... but for some reason now the import isn't working. I haven't touched it but it can't find geopy even if I reinstall it using "pip install geopy". Any thoughts?

Comment: @BrysonLichtenberg Yes - Your Python runtime environment is probably broken. Have you tried running from command line rather than your IDE?

Comment: Interesting. Yeah when I run the script using the terminal in VS it works...